Total Eclipse - future hits
Now that parts of the USA have experienced a total eclipse, the song "Total Eclipse of the Heart" has become very popular again. The artist cannot have anticipated that an actual eclipse would have revived the song years after it was first a hit.
So my question is - are there any other songs that might become popular again if certain world events come to pass? Name the song and the world event that might revive it.
I thought of the REM song "The end of the world as we know it."  But there must be lots of others…

Personally, I was enjoying Johnny Cash's "Ring of Fire," even though this wasn't an annular eclipse. I was in partial totality anyway. And I guess REM's wouldn't have much time to enjoy its boost...

Unexpected upswings are quite common as soon as the song is featured in some successful movie or video game.

Given the recent solar activity and the glow in the UK night sky, I'm waiting for Northern Lights to start trending.
